# How to convert FromStrRadixErr to ParseIntError?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm trying to build a generic wrapper around `std::<T>::from_str_radix`. According to the documentation, `from_str_radix` returns `Result<T, ParseIntError>`. But

```
fn foo<T: num_traits::Num>() -> Result<T, std::num::ParseIntError> {
    T::from_str_radix("4242", 10)
}
```

won't compile:

> error: mismatched types:  expected `core::result::Result<T,
>   core::num::ParseIntError>`,
>       found `core::result::Result<T, <T as num_traits::Num>::FromStrRadixErr>`

On the other hand, this

```
fn main() {
    let x: Result<u8, std::num::ParseIntError> = foo();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn foo<T: num_traits::Num>() -> Result<T, <T as num_traits::Num>::FromStrRadixErr> {
    T::from_str_radix("4242", 10)
}
```

compiles fine and prints the expected result

> Err(ParseIntError { kind: Overflow })

To my mind, both are the same situation, but obviously I'm wrong. Can anybody explain to me the difference and possibly show me a solution?

Comment: Please add from where you are trying to get the `num_traits::Num` trait, the first compile error is `error: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `num_traits` [E0433]`

Comment: It's fetching traits from crate called `num_traits`. However you can partially copy the implementation. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0b7a2c5790e1c344a76663cc767f8790&version=stable&backtrace=0 for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to convert `FromStrRadixErr` to `ParseIntError`?

It's not possible. Some errors, like [`io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Error.html), allow you to create a instance with a causing error, so you can create a error that wraps another error. If `ParseIntError` had such functionality, you could create a `ParseIntError` caused by a `FromStrRadixErr` error, but `ParseIntError` does not.

> Can anybody explain to me the difference?

This code:

```
fn foo<T: num_traits::Num>() -> Result<T, std::num::ParseIntError> {
    T::from_str_radix("4242", 10)
}
```

does not compile because the returned type of `T::from_str_radix` is `Result<T, FromStrRadixErr>` not `Result<T, ParseIntError>`. Changing the return type (as you did) to `Result<T, FromStrRadixErr>`, solves the problem.

This code:

```
fn main() {
    let x: Result<u8, std::num::ParseIntError> = foo();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn foo<T: num_traits::Num>() -> Result<T, <T as num_traits::Num>::FromStrRadixErr> {
    T::from_str_radix("4242", 10)
}
```

compiles fine because the `Num` trait implementation for `u8` [defines](https://github.com/rust-num/num/blob/ace0951f2ad4e1e48299a5d80d70a65d8a2f78b9/traits/src/lib.rs#L48) `FromStrRadixErr = ParseIntError`.

If you change `u8` to `f32`:

```
let x: Result<f32, std::num::ParseIntError> = foo();
```

it fails to compile. The reason it that the `Num` implementation for `f32` [defines](https://github.com/rust-num/num/blob/ace0951f2ad4e1e48299a5d80d70a65d8a2f78b9/traits/src/lib.rs#L77) `FromStrRadixErr = ParseFloatError` and `ParseFloatError` is not `ParseIntError`.

> and possibly show me a solution?

You said that you are trying to build a generic wrapper around `std::<T>::from_str_radix`, but your examples use `T::from_str_radix` where `T: Num`, so you are trying to write a wrapper around `Num::from_str_radix`.

One option is to use `Num` and `FromStrRadixErr` directly instead of creating a wrapper, in the end, `Num` is the wrapper.

Maybe you want to restrict the wrapper to primitive integers and use `ParseIntError`. In this case, you can add the restriction `FromStrRadixErr = ParseIntError`:

```
fn foo<T>() -> Result<T, std::num::ParseIntError>
    where T: num_traits::Num<FromStrRadixErr = std::num::ParseIntError>,
{
    T::from_str_radix("4242", 10)
}
```

Comment: Thanks malbarbo. Your hint about the types being _defined_ as equal was the missing link. And I would never have guessed the syntax to require that.

Comment: I already had tried the restriction `T: num::traits::PrimInt` since this is what I'm interested in. But your proposal just works :-)